# RepeatOnLifecycle not executed when DialogFragment is open

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that opens a DialogFragment with some settings in it. When I change the settings in the DialogFragment I want the underlying Fragment to collect the changes.
I use a view model and StateFlows to store the settings and have collectors set up in the Fragment, however, they are never called. But the view model is updated correctly.
Is it because of the `viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` that  the collectors are not called because the DialogFragment is showing? But the background fragment is still active.

When I use `MutableLiveData` instead of `MutableStateFlow` and make an observer instead of the collector, it works. So it must have something to do with the repeatOnLifecycle.

```kotlin
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    // Dropped the other functions, e.g. onCreate, for simplicity

    val settings by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.testButton.setOnClickListener {
            val settingsFragment = SettingsDialogFragment()
            settingsFragment.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "settings")
        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                settings.lowerState.collect {
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "lowerState switched")
                }
                settings.upperState.collect {
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "upperState switched")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class SettingsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val lowerState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val upperState: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(true)
}
```

The dialog fragment is a simple dialog with no special functions

```kotlin
class SettingsDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSettingsDialogBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val settings: SettingsViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        _binding = FragmentRecordingSettingsDialogBinding.inflate(
            layoutInflater,
            null,
            false
        )
        _binding!!.settings = settings

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())

        return builder.setView(binding.root).create()
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="settings"
            type="com.example.SettingsViewModel"/>
    </data>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:checked="@={settings.upperState}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:checked="@={settings.lowerState}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: I haven't used data binding, but https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#stateflow says you need to set a ``lifecycleOwner`` on your binding, to give the ``StateFlow`` a scope, so maybe that's why it's not firing?

Comment: Good hint, sadly it is still not firing. I added the DialogFragment as well as the backgrounds fragment lifeCycleOwner, but neither worked.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably want to use the same ``lifecycleOwner`` as the one that's observing the ``Flow``s (you might want to use ``viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`` instead of just ``lifecycleScope``, since your stuff in the coroutine is running on the former). Also make sure  that ``MainActivity.settings`` property is giving everything the same VM - that's a weird way to retrieve it, instead of the usual e.g. ``by activityViewModels()``. If the LiveData version works it's probably fine, but it might help you track the problem down!

Comment: I tried using the same `lifecycleOwner` for the flow observer as well as the binding, but no luck. Even with explicit `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`. And `MainActivity.setzings` is a static member with the current viewModel, changing it to `by activityViewModels()` had no effect

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `collect` twice within the same `launch`? `collect` on a `StateFlow` never finishes, so your second collect call will never, ever be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having taken your code - just the barebones I was able to get this to work.
You can see that there is logging from the flows collecting in `SomeFragment`, which are changed by the switches :

[image: test app showing logging]

Thoughts :

I assume that by using the delegate `by activityViewModels()` to get your `SettingsViewModel` that both Fragments have a common parent `Activity`, thus supplied the same view model instance.

Your `collect { .. }` tail calls are suspending, so you will only EVER get the first collector to collect anyway, in this case :

```
settingsViewModel.lowerState
        .collect { .. suspending block in this coroutine nothing passed this will execute as FlowCollector still "collecting" and pushing into this block .. }
```

The right syntax for multiple flows in the same `suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit` block is something like :

```
 settingsViewModel.lowerState
        .onEach { Log.e("DEBUG", "lowerState switched") }
        .launchIn(this)
 settingsViewModel.upperState
        .onEach { Log.e("DEBUG", "upperState switched") }
        .launchIn(this)
```

This way `launchIn()` is a short-cut to the tail call `scope.launch { collect() }` - this launches a new coroutine with no `suspend` block - handled by `onEach { .. }`.

Other than that not really much to say other than maybe take your own barebones code and try in a new project to elinmate this logic as the root problem.  With all the "helper" functions Android creates around scopes/ lifecycles it does make this code much harder to test in isolation as it relies on framework classes and LifeCycleOwner callbacks and IMHO make it harder to understand - but .. just my opinion and something that came to mind as I was copying and looking at the code.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of ***DialogFragments*** which might not have a View sometimes. For ***DialogFragments***, you should use the **lifecycleOwner**.

Under the hood **repeatOnLifecycle** suspends the calling coroutine, re-launches the block when the lifecycle moves in and out of the target state in a new coroutine, and resumes the calling coroutine when the ***Lifecycle is destroyed***. So the coroutine that calls repeatOnLifecycle won’t resume executing until the lifecycle is destroyed.

One of the possible solutions here would be to use ***Lifecycle.State.RESUMED*** with the **lifecycle** instead of **viewLifecycleOwner**

```
 lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
            // Repeat when the lifecycle is RESUMED, cancel when PAUSED
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. It is mentioned here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda
"Important: Fragments should always use the viewLifecycleOwner to trigger UI updates. However, that’s not the case for DialogFragments which might not have a View sometimes. For DialogFragments, you can use the lifecycleOwner."

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using this code as when the dialog will close resume state will be call of somefragment.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
                    settings.lowerState.collect {
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "lowerState switched")
                    }
                    settings.upperState.collect {
                        Log.e("DEBUG", "upperState switched")
                    }
                }
            }
```